# Enabling autologin in ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS server on raspi?

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi, auto-login

I don't want theinitial screen that asks for username/password in beginning of Ubuntu Server 20.04 since I am using this OS on raspberry device which runs a code in background on startup. How do skip username/password screen or equivalently enable autologin?

I have followed tons of article over SO and web, but my version doesn't even seems to have folders where they want me to edit setting files. For example there is no 'init' folder once I get into `/etc` folder, lightdm, gdm3 folder, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The program that's producing the prompt you're seeing is `agetty`. You can change the systemd config to automatically log you in as some user on every terminal, or on just one.

#### For every terminal

Use `systemctl edit getty@.service` to change the `ExecStart=-` line to `/sbin/agetty -a $DESIRED_USERNAME --noclear %I $TERM`

#### For just one terminal

Launch `systemctl edit getty@tty1.service`

Copy the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` into your text editor

Change the `ExecStart=-` line to `/sbin/agetty -a $DESIRED_USERNAME --noclear %I $TERM`

Solution stolen from this question and answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253928/how-to-configure-agetty-to-autologon-on-only-one-terminal

Don't edit systemd service files directly (thanks kamilcuk).

Comment: `For every terminal

Change the ExecStart=- line in /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` NO! Do not edit files in `/lib`! Do `systemctl edit getty@.service` and add `ExecStart=-` in there or create `/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/override.conf`. `Copy /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service to /lib/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service` NO! Do not create files in `/lib`. Do `systemctl edit getty@tty1.service` or create `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` file.